# can sharepoint search service work with form authentication?

Tags: wss

I have windows sharepoint services 2007 installed on windows server 2008.
I enabled forum authentication on one of web application.
the search is not working , it can't find anything.
the search is enabled on the webapplication and I am sure because it was working
properly when the webapplication is windows authenticated but switching to form authentication make the search not working.

the search is giving no error just nothing found,empty result.

I had microsoft office server 2007 before wss 2007 and it was the same problem,I uninstall it and install wss 2007 but I didn't notice any difference,the same problem...

Comment: I found the following article that answer my question but unfortunatellly it is not a solution it is just a matter of fact
http://support.microsoft.com/kb/934577#appliesto